# OpenCV Assertion Fail in clEnqueueWriteBuffer for people detection

Tags: c++, opencv

Using Ubuntu 16.04 and OpenCV 3.2. NOTE: eventually i will be transferring this code over to a windows system so please let me know if the issue is ubuntu specific. I am trying to use the OpenCV peopledetection sample and I am getting an assertion error.  Ive trimmed down the code into something more simple than the sample given. The code used is shown here:

```
int main()
{
VideoCapture cam(0);
cam.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,320);
cam.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,240);


Mat img;
HOGDescriptor hog;

hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getPeopleDetector());

namedWindow("video capture",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
vector<Rect> found,found_filtered;


while(true)
{
    cam >> img;
    cout << "ep" <<endl;
    hog.detectMultiScale(img, found, 0, Size(8,8), Size(32,32), 1.05, 2);

    size_t i, j;
    for (i=0; i<found.size(); i++)
    {
        Rect r = found[i];
        for (j=0; j<found.size(); j++)
            if (j!=i && (r & found[j])==r)
                break;
        if (j==found.size())
            found_filtered.push_back(r);
    }
    for (i=0; i<found_filtered.size(); i++)
    {
        Rect r = found_filtered[i];
        r.x += cvRound(r.width*0.1);
        r.width = cvRound(r.width*0.8);
        r.y += cvRound(r.height*0.06);
        r.height = cvRound(r.height*0.9);
        rectangle(img, r.tl(), r.br(), cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 2);
    }

    imshow("video capture", img);
    if (waitKey(20) == 27)
        break;
}
```

The assertion error is shown here:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (clEnqueueWriteBuffer(q, (cl_mem)u->handle, CL_TRUE, dstrawofs, total, alignedPtr.getAlignedPtr(), 0, 0, 0) >= 0) in upload, file /home/alex/Desktop/OpenCV_tutorial/OpenCV/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp, line 5129
>   terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>     what():  /Desktop/OpenCV_tutorial/OpenCV/opencv-3.2.0/modules/core/src/ocl.cpp:5129: error: (-215) clEnqueueWriteBuffer(q, (cl_mem)u->handle, CL_TRUE, dstrawofs, total, alignedPtr.getAlignedPtr(), 0, 0, 0) >= 0 in function upload

I believe I have pinpointed the exception to be thrown at this line:

> hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor::getPeopleDetector());

I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to opencv in general but i would appreciate help with solving this error.  What steps can i take to solve this issue?